# Grafana - Write: broken pipe

Tags: postgresql, tcp, grafana, broken-pipe

since the upgrade of grafana to 7.3.5 we have encountered “broken pipe” problems.
The dashboards all put in error after a few hours of use, as seen below.

```
"write tcp 127.0.0.1:59132->127.0.0.1:5432:write: broken pipe"
```

Grafana is linked to a postgresql 10 database.

A restart of the grafana services makes it possible to solve it, for x time but this solution is not viable.

Do you have an idea ?

thanks in advance